# Why does a record-locking file remain after I close access database?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I see Microsoft record locking file remain after i close the database. I run vba from access, if for some reason it gets not responding(while checking some code), then i close it. After that i still see record-locking file remain .

Comment: Can you delete the lock file from Windows Explorer after you close Access?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your code is interacting with a database object. That connection doesn't get closed properly when you close the application mid-execution, so it never clears up the lock file.